# Permutation or combination? Cards and piles problem.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> ""As a very straightforward problem, suppose we want to find the
> number of ways 52 cards can be dealt among four players with each
> player getting 13 cards (JEE 1979). Call the players as P1 to P4. Then
> P1’s hand can be chosen in 52C13 ways. Once it is chosen, we are left
> with 39 cards, from which P2’s hand can be chosen in 39C13 ways.
> Continuing in this way, the total number of deals
> is 52C13.39C13.26C13 which simplifies to 52! (13!)4 .
>
> In the preceding
> problem, suppose however, that we want to divide the 52 cards into
> four piles with 17 cards in three piles and just one card in the
> fourth. Reasoning as above, it is tempting to think that here the
> answer is 5217.35C17.18C17
> = 52!/ ${17!}^{3}$ . But this is not quite so. This would be the right answer if there were four players and we were giving 17 cards to each
> of P1, P2 and P3 and one card to P4. But as the problem stands, there
> are no players. We are merely dividing the cards into 4 piles. This is
> equivalent to saying that the hands of the first three players can be
> permuted among themselves. This can be done in 3! i.e., in 6 ways. So
> the correct answer is 52!/6 (${17!}^{3})$.""

What exactly is the author trying to convey? Is it that we were actually permuting in the case of people (if it was that why is combination being used?), and are using combination in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider both situations as dividing the cards into *groups*, and the difference arises depending on whether the groups are **labeled** or **unlabeled** (Note here that a group can be labeled by name or size)

In the first case, you are dividing the cards to $4$ labeled groups.

In the second case, you have three unlabeled groups and one distinct group labeled by size.
Since we can't distinguish between the three unlabelled groups, we need to divide by $3!$

*ADDED*

Also, note that $$\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}\binom{13}{13}$$ and $$\frac{52!}{13!13!13!13!}$$  and $$\dbinom{52}{13,13,13,13}$$ are just three forms in which the multinomial coefficient (extended form of the binomial coefficient with $>2$  mutually exclusive and exhaustive events), is written

Comment: How do you know if a group is distinguishable or indistinguishable?

Comment: @twbnrftw: In the first case, each player is obviously distinguishable (labeled by name). In the second case, there are $4$ heaps, of which only one is distinguishable because it has a different size from the others.